# firefox not displaying border-image when using jquery for css

Tags: jquery, css, image, firefox, backbone.js

I am developing a web app using the require.js and backbone.js frameworks.

I am trying to set the CSS property of 'boder-image' using jquery.css method. It works well in chrome and safari. But, in firefox, the first load (when there is no cache) always results in the border not being drawn. If I refresh with F5, the rendering is good. But, if I use Ctrl+F5, the border image is gone.

I dont know how to solve this problem. It would be great if someone can give a hint.

This is how I set the border-image property in the code.

```
obj.css             
            'border-image': 'url(/static/images/border-background-green.png) 40 40 40 40 fill stretch'
            '-moz-border-image': 'url(/static/images/border-background-green.png) 40 40 40 40 stretch'
            '-webkit-border-image': 'url(/static/images/border-background-green.png) 40 40 40 40 stretch'
            '-o-border-image': 'url(/static/images/border-background-gray.png) 40 40 40 40 stretch'             
            'border-width' : '10px 10px 10px 10px'
```

**:::::::Edit::::::**

I found that this problem occurs when the property "border-image" is applied to a table. When I change the table element to "div", the problem disappeared. Took 4 hrs and a good night sleep to get to this!!

Comment: Not sure, but try to add `!important` key word after CSS settings : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/ Otherwise, create an example with fiddle.net

Comment: I am not sure if jsfiddle could represent the problem. I will give a shot.
Also, I tried adding the image to obj before setting the css. It seems to work now. The image is hidden from display by setting it to be invisible.